# Method Explanation - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently trying to learn Swift and i'm having a little trouble understanding the method parameters in Swift. Now I understand everything in this code block.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

except `"didSelectRowAtIndexPath"`.

What purpose does this code have inside the parameters? Unlike `tableView: UITableView` or `indexPath: NSIndexPath` it doesn't have a class object following the naming convention.

So what does it do? I get that it has something to do with selecting a row at the index path but is it just naming convention, method call?

Thanks guys.

Comment: As in the referenced thread, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is an *external parameter name* (documented in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the name of this parameter from the call site. So when you call the method (which in this case you shouldn't ;)) you would do it like this:

```
 dataSource.tableView(myTableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: theIndexPath)
```

But within the method the parameter is accessed with the name `indexPath`.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit confused. Isn't indexPath: NSIndexPath) the parameter and superclass?  I'm just confused how didSelectRowAtIndexPath fits into all of this. Because when I remove it Xcode gives me an error.  Also what do you mean by call site?

Comment: No, `indexPath` is the internal name of the parameter, `NSIndexPath` is the class of the parameter, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is the external name of the parameter. You can't remove it, because it's in the API definition of didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You can't change the Apple-API. The call site is the code where you call this method.